# CVS: Get the state of some branch in some date

Tags: tags, cvs, sticky

I have a big project with branches. All development is concentrated in the branch. 
I want to get the state of this branch at some time ago, but can't

```
 cvs up -r branch_name -D 2010-05-01
```

gives me (in cvs status Makefile) the sticky tag, but the newest version of file, not at 2010-05-01

```
 cvs up -D 2010-05-01 -r branch_name
```

ignores a tag and updated to that Date of the HEAD

```
 cvs up -r branch_name:2010-05-01
```

doesn't work too, it ignores date and updates to current state of branch.

Comment: I seem to remember there was a special syntax involving colons but I can't find it in the docs right now...

Comment: hmm, it's only documented for the `-j` option (i.e. merge) but I think it might just work for `-r`, too:  `cvs up -r branch_name:2010-05-01` (not tested)

Comment: Oliver Giesen, please, add this as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cvs update -PdC -r BRANCH-NAME-HERE -D "Saturday, May 1, 2010 0:00:00 AM UTC"`

If you know the time, add that...

Comment: What is the meaning of "P", "d" and "C" options?

Comment: * P = prune empty directories

* d = if there are any dirs in the repo that are not in the workspace, create them

Not sure what "C" is but have always used it for this...

Comment: This doesn't seem to give the entire branch at that point in time. It only gives files that have changed since the original branch. So I'm find that files are missing when I check out by date. Is there any way to get the entire branch?

Comment: What is the difference between your command and the one from @osgx? The only difference I see is the order and the date formatting. Did this really matter?

Comment: "P" means "Prune empty directories.", "d" - "Build directories, like checkout does." and "C" - "Overwrite locally modified files with clean repository copies.". "D" option parses date with `Make_Date`/`get_date` functions - defined in [`cvs/src/main.c`](https://sources.debian.net/src/cvs/2:1.12.13%2Breal-15/src/main.c/) and [`cvs/lib/getdate.c`](http://sources.debian.net/src/cvs/2:1.12.13%2Breal-15/lib/getdate.c/) (from [`cvs/lib/getdate.y`](http://sources.debian.net/src/cvs/2:1.12.13%2Breal-15/lib/getdate.y/); they should be able to parse "`2004-04-29 20:24:22`". Don't know real diff with my.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
cvs up -r branch_name:2010-05-01
```

The colon syntax is only documented for the `-j` option but **probably** works for `-r`, too.

Comment: is does smth strange, may be it uses some different format of the date?

It does update to older version, but not version at 2010-05-01.

Comment: Hmm, there is `parse_tagdate` call in `-r` option parsing - [cvs/src/update.c:205](https://sources.debian.net/src/cvs/2:1.12.13%2Breal-15/src/update.c/#L205) (`case 'r': parse_tagdate (&tag, &date, optarg); `) which should parse date: [cvs/src/main.c:1146](http://sources.debian.net/src/cvs/2:1.12.13%2Breal-15/src/main.c/?hl=1168#L1146) "Parse a string of the form TAG[:DATE], where TAG could be the empty string."; it parses date with the same `Make_Date`/`get_date` as in `-D` option.